# Passé composé de « arriver »

Tags: grammaire, passé-composé

Le verbe « arriver » a deux significations principales :

1. Parvenir à destination, à un état, à une situation: « On arrive à
   Paris demain. »
2. Réussir à faire quelque chose: « Je n'arrive pas à comprendre les raisons de son geste. »

Normalement on utilise le verbe « être » comme auxiliaire d'« arriver » au passé composé. Cette règle est-elle valable pour tous les sens d'« arriver » ou seulement pour le premier ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oui. Par exemple, « j’y suis arrivé » veut à la fois dire je suis arrivé à destination et j’ai réussi à faire quelque chose.